# Text in Android Design Preview is blurry after the Artic fox 2020.3.1 update

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

Everything was great before the update, but as soon as it updated to ***Arctic Fox 2020.3.1*** this issue came up. I tried to restart the android studio, restore settings to default, created new project, etc. but nothing worked. Anyone has any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried to select another device such as Pixel 5 in the preview

Comment: Also try closing all the other windows, it is maybe because the preview window maybe too small

Comment: Did you try zooming the design preview window in??